# Determine Notes client language with LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is it possible to use LotusScript to determine which language (such as English or Spanish) a user's Lotus Notes client has?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is pretty easy: The language that the user selected is in the notes.ini. You can use `NotesSession.GetEnvironmentString( "UserInterface", True )` to read it. If this value is empty, then the interface is english.

Unfortunately you do NOT see, which language is installed. If you install a german client and switch the Userinterface to englisch, then the notes.ini- Variable will be empty...

Comment: Thanks, haven't yet had the opportunity to test this but will do so.